# Filter NULL values in reports?

Tags: dashboard, filters, custom-reports, null

How can I filter out NULL values from within the reports editor for a text field?
[image: Reports Editor Filter]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want a not null field, just set the field not equal to blank, i.e., leave the filter value box empty.

Answer (score 0):

You can type "NULL" into that box.